# Card view alignToBottom and more not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with 4 card views inside, Each one will be pinned to a corner of the relative layout (top left, top right. bottom left, bottom right) However, only the first two card views (as sorted by the code) are acting as they should, whereas the last two (as sorted by the code) are sticking to the top left corner.

I have no clue as to why this is happening but I feel like it's something pretty obvious that I'm being stumped by.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Silly me. I had the relative layout inside a scroll view, meaning there wasn't a bottom. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Try above code.